# Is it possible to query Azure data warehouse within log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-synapse

I have a scenario where I would like to query Azure Data warehouse tables within the Log Analytics workspace and using those records I need to create a result set and prepare a chart.

I do see some objects in log analytics workspace like a database, table but not sure what is the purpose and are these objects specific to a resource or generic and how to use them I couldn't get documentation for these objects can somebody guide me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use Azure Log Analytics to query Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Use [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-sql-dw?view=sql-server-ver15) to connect and query data in Azure SQL data warehouse.

[Recommended tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/overview-sql-tools?view=sql-server-ver15) for querying data in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

> Azure Log Analytics is used to write, execute, and manage Azure Monitor log queries in the Azure portal. You can use Log Analytics queries to search for terms, identify trends, analyze patterns, and provide many other insights from your data.

For more information about log queries, see [Overview of log queries in Azure Monito](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview)r.

For a detailed tutorial on writing log queries, see [Get started with log queries in Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-queries).